# Pymongo KeyError: '$err' MongoDB Atlas

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x, mongodb-atlas

I'm following this https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-python-and-mongodb introductory tutorial. I can connect to the cluster fine with mongo shell, but not with pymongo (Python: 3.6.1, Pymongo 3.4.0). Pymongo works okay with a local mongodb. What is the problem? Below is the exception I get:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
-----
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-22-1c9d47341338> in <module>()
----> 1 server_status_result = db.command('serverStatus')
      2 pprint(server_status_result)

/home/tim/.virtualenvs/main/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pymongo/database.py in command(self, command, value, check, 
allowable_errors, read_preference, codec_options, **kwargs)
489         """
490         client = self.__client
--> 491         with client._socket_for_reads(read_preference) as 
(sock_info, slave_ok):
492             return self._command(sock_info, command, slave_ok, 
value,
493                                  check, allowable_errors, 
read_preference,

/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in __enter__(self)
 80     def __enter__(self):
 81         try:
---> 82             return next(self.gen)
 83         except StopIteration:
 84             raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield") from None

/home/tim/.virtualenvs/main/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py in _socket_for_reads(self, 
read_preference)
857         topology = self._get_topology()
858         single = topology.description.topology_type == 
TOPOLOGY_TYPE.Single
--> 859         with self._get_socket(read_preference) as sock_info:
860             slave_ok = (single and not sock_info.is_mongos) or (
861                 preference != ReadPreference.PRIMARY)

/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in __enter__(self)
 80     def __enter__(self):
 81         try:
---> 82             return next(self.gen)
 83         except StopIteration:
 84             raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield") from None

/home/tim/.virtualenvs/main/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py in _get_socket(self, selector)
823         server = self._get_topology().select_server(selector)
824         try:
--> 825             with server.get_socket(self.__all_credentials) as 
sock_info:
826                 yield sock_info
827         except NetworkTimeout:

/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in __enter__(self)
 80     def __enter__(self):
 81         try:
---> 82             return next(self.gen)
 83         except StopIteration:
 84             raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield") from None

/home/tim/.virtualenvs/main/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pymongo/server.py in get_socket(self, all_credentials, 
checkout)
166     @contextlib.contextmanager
167     def get_socket(self, all_credentials, checkout=False):
--> 168         with self.pool.get_socket(all_credentials, checkout) 
as sock_info:
169             yield sock_info
170 

/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in __enter__(self)
 80     def __enter__(self):
 81         try:
---> 82             return next(self.gen)
 83         except StopIteration:
 84             raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield") from None

/home/tim/.virtualenvs/main/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pymongo/pool.py in get_socket(self, all_credentials, 
checkout)
790         sock_info = self._get_socket_no_auth()
791         try:
--> 792             sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)
793             yield sock_info
794         except:

/home/tim/.virtualenvs/main/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pymongo/pool.py in check_auth(self, all_credentials)
510 
511             for credentials in cached - authset:
--> 512                 auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
513                 self.authset.add(credentials)
514 

/home/tim/.virtualenvs/main/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pymongo/auth.py in authenticate(credentials, sock_info)
468     mechanism = credentials.mechanism
469     auth_func = _AUTH_MAP.get(mechanism)
--> 470     auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
471 
472 

/home/tim/.virtualenvs/main/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pymongo/auth.py in _authenticate_default(credentials, 
sock_info)
448 def _authenticate_default(credentials, sock_info):
449     if sock_info.max_wire_version >= 3:
--> 450         return _authenticate_scram_sha1(credentials, 
sock_info)
451     else:
452         return _authenticate_mongo_cr(credentials, sock_info)

/home/tim/.virtualenvs/main/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pymongo/auth.py in _authenticate_scram_sha1(credentials, 
sock_info)
227                ('conversationId', res['conversationId']),
228                ('payload', Binary(client_final))])
--> 229     res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
230 
231     parsed = _parse_scram_response(res['payload'])

/home/tim/.virtualenvs/main/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pymongo/pool.py in command(self, dbname, spec, slave_ok, 
read_preference, codec_options, check, allowable_errors, check_keys, 
read_concern, write_concern, parse_write_concern_error, collation)
422         # Catch socket.error, KeyboardInterrupt, etc. and close 
ourselves.
423         except BaseException as error:
--> 424             self._raise_connection_failure(error)
425 
426     def send_message(self, message, max_doc_size):

/home/tim/.virtualenvs/main/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pymongo/pool.py in _raise_connection_failure(self, error)
550             _raise_connection_failure(self.address, error)
551         else:
--> 552             raise error
553 
554     def __eq__(self, other):

/home/tim/.virtualenvs/main/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pymongo/pool.py in command(self, dbname, spec, slave_ok, 
read_preference, codec_options, check, allowable_errors, check_keys, 
read_concern, write_concern, parse_write_concern_error, collation)
417                            read_concern,
418                            
parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error,
--> 419                            collation=collation)
420         except OperationFailure:
421             raise

/home/tim/.virtualenvs/main/lib/python3.6/site-p 
ackages/pymongo/network.py in command(sock, dbname, spec, slave_ok, 
is_mongos, read_preference, codec_options, check, allowable_errors, 
address, check_keys, listeners, max_bson_size, read_concern, 
parse_write_concern_error, collation)
108         response = receive_message(sock, 1, request_id)
109         unpacked = helpers._unpack_response(
--> 110             response, codec_options=codec_options)
111 
112         response_doc = unpacked['data'][0]

/home/tim/.virtualenvs/main/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pymongo/helpers.py in _unpack_response(response, cursor_id, 
codec_options)
126         # Fake the ok field if it doesn't exist.
127         error_object.setdefault("ok", 0)
--> 128         if error_object["$err"].startswith("not master"):
129             raise NotMasterError(error_object["$err"], 
error_object)
130         elif error_object.get("code") == 50:

KeyError: '$err'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is an Atlas bug, I've reported it to the team. The bug is, if you *fail* to log in to Atlas because your username or password are incorrect, it replies in a way that makes PyMongo throw a `KeyError` instead of the proper `OperationFailure("auth failed")`.

PyMongo does work with Atlas, however, if you properly format your connection string with your username and password. Make sure your username and password are URL-quoted. Substitute your username and password into this Python code:

```
from urllib import quote_plus

print(quote_plus('MY USERNAME'))
print(quote_plus('MY PASSWORD'))
```

Take the output and put it into the connection string Atlas gave you, e.g. if your username is jesse@example.com and your password is "foo:bar", put that in the first part of the string, and get the rest of the string from the Atlas control panel for your account:

```
mongodb://jesse%40example.com:foo%3Abar/@cluster0-shard-00-00-abc.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-abc.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-abc.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin
```

Note how "jesse@example.com" has become "jesse%40example.com", and "foo:bar" has become "foo%3Abar".

Comment: Worked thanks. Python 3 import `from urllib.parse import quote_plus`. Would it be possible to add it to the docs that a username/password with special characters needs to be quoted to work?

Comment: That's documented here: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/authentication.html  ... but I've also asked the Atlas team to put that information into the Atlas dashboard.